# Not using a data store with sails

Tags: javascript, mongoose, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have an use case where my current sails app needs to use a datastore in certain environments (staging) and does not need any kind of persistence in a different environment (production). How can I set this up?

Comment: Help me understand. Say `User.create` stores in a database in staging. What is it supposed to do in production?

Comment: The piece of code that needs persistence will be disabled in production.